# Limiting editable fields in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, write-protect

Can I limit only specific fields to be non-editable by users in Excel? 
The 'Protect sheet' function only offers protection to the entire file with specific fields editable, I want the opposite (most fields editable, some excluded).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you select the whole sheet by clicking in the gap at the top-left of the row/column headings, you can then make all the cells for the sheet unprotected. You can then change individual cells back to protected.